# Variable sized structures within another variable sized structure

Tags: c, struct

I have variable sized structures within a variable structure.  What is a good way to walk each sub table?  The buffer is byte-packed and is available at 'address'.  No need to malloc.  Cannot do indexing in while loop,  Is offsetting with table sizes is the only option?

---

```
void walk_master_table (ulong address)
{
    int count=0;
    Master_table* masterTable = (Master_table*)address;

    while(masterTable->subTables[count].subTable1.length)
    {
        //do some processing;
        // advance to next sub table

        count ++;  /* <-- I cannot do this because the offset is not */
                   /*guaranteed and the buffer is byte-packed*/
    }
}


struct Master_table
{
    uint Total_MasterTable_Length;
    struct SUB_TABLES subTables[1];
}

struct SUB_TABLES 
{
   union {
    struct subTable1;
    struct subTable2;
    struct subTable3;
    struct subTable4;
    char buffer[128];
    };
}

/*each subtable is of different size.*/

struct subTable1
{
    uint thisTable_length;
    char [xx];
}

struct subTable1
{
    uint thisTable_length;
    char [yy];
}

struct subTable3
{
    uint thisTable_length;
    char [zz];
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a variable sized structure. Your `strict Master_table` size is `sizeof(uint) + sizeof(struct SUB_TABLES)` plus any padding needed (probably none in this case). That you wish to put more than one SUB_TABLES structure out here is your problem, not the language's. Your only real option, as I see it, is to change SUB_TABLES to a proper pointer, not an improperly sized array.

Comment: @mah, C does offer flexible array members, which could be what the OP is after.  The standard does not use the terminology "variable sized" to describe `struct`s having such a member, but that's not an unreasonable colloquialism.  Looking more closely, however, I don't think flexible array members quite fits.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Is there something in C that is of undeterminable size? I'm not saying there's anything wrong with the definition of the struct/array in this case, and while a somewhat obscure pattern it's definitely one that has its place. That said, the language provides no support for it, so nesting it as the OP wants to do is not valid for this pattern.

Comment: @mah, not exactly.  See C99 section 6.7.2.1, clause 16 for a description of flexible array members.  That is *not* what the OP has, but it looks similar to a (non-standard) form that was used to the same effect prior to C99.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I don't know the language spec section for this, but https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html states _A structure containing a flexible array member, or a union containing such a structure (possibly recursively), may not be a member of a structure or an element of an array_ (though it also states that there are gcc extensions to allow it to work). I guess your concern is with my statement of there not being any such thing as a variable sized structure -- a statement which is not exactly correct (but in the spirit of things, perhaps not exactly incorrect either?)

Comment: @mah, yes, my objection was to your statement denying the existence of variable-sized structures.  Certainly the OP's code does not contain any, but it does seem that flexible array members may be what he's after.  Neither the standard nor GCC would forbid his `Master_table.subTables` from being a flexible member, and that's more or less what he's asking about.  Still, I acknowledge that `struct`s with a flexible member are weird, and in some ways not "variable-size" at all.

Answer (score 0):

In the first place, it's bad form to pass pointers as integer values.  Use a `void *` if you want to avoid naming a specific type, but if you're always going to cast to a specific pointer type then you should just declare the argument to have that type.

More to the point, you appear to be using a non-standard form of what is now known as a flexible array member of your `struct`.  Your code exhibits undefined behavior when you access `masterTable->subTables[count]` with `count` larger than 1.  The similar form standardized in C99 (which has defined behavior for more values of `count`) would require you to declare `struct Master_table` a bit differently:

```
struct Master_table
{
    uint Total_MasterTable_Length;
    struct SUB_TABLES subTables[];  /* no declared size */
}
```

The usual usage is to dynamically allocate memory for such objects, enough for the fixed-size part plus however many elements you need of the flexible array.  It is then permitted to access the allocated space via the flexible array member, provided that you do not access past the space allocated for it.

However, your code comment that it is incorrect to access successive subtables by incrementing an index into `Master_table.subTables`, if correct, seems to indicate that data starting at address `address` do not, in fact, constitute a valid representation of a `struct Master_table` (as you have declared it), flexible member or not.

Arrays are sequences of **fixed-size** objects.  Your `struct SUB_TABLES` is a valid array element type, but it is not variable-size.  Since it has only one member, it is the size of that member (a union), and the union is the size of its largest member.  Every `struct SUB_TABLES` object is that size.

If what you actually have for subtables is a sequence of `struct`s variously of types `struct subTable1` - `struct subTable4`, packed without gaps, and those subtables are of different sizes, then that is **not** an array of `struct SUB_TABLES`.  Moreover, I don't see how you can figure out what it is even at runtime if you have only the data you present.

If your subtable data are strictly of the form { `table_length`, `char[table_length]` }, then you should declare `subTables` as a `void *`.  You will need to use casts and pointer arithmetic to work your way through the data.  You could perhaps use a subtable `struct` type with a flexible member to help, but declaring `subTables` as an array of such would not have a useful effect.